# FTP server (open source?) with paid support

Tags: open-source, ftp

Corporate has asked us to look for an FTP server solution with paid support.  Our team has a preference for open source, and would normally support it ourselves.  But the guys at the top want that secure feeling of paying someone to CYA.  Soooooo....what kind of options are out there for FTP server that supports FTP, FTPS, SFTP, plus has a web-based front end so people could transfer files that way...that also has the option of paid support?

Any recommendations?

Comment: What is "CYA" and why don't they trust your team?

Comment: @John Gardeniers: Cover Your Ass? Trust me, paid support is like a warm warm blanket: when the fit hits the shan, they're there to take the blame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd take a look at [Go Anywhere Services](http://www.goanywheremft.com/products/services) if you absolutely need something professionally supported and secured.

Or you can just let a 3rd party host your FTP, and make the security their problem.

Mind you, I think it's overkill. As long as it's patched, Windows FTP, Linux FTP, it's all good, and it's not difficult to force SFTP either. You're going to be spending a lot of money.

edit: Alternately, you could just get RHEL with a support contract, and use standard Linux FTP. Lot of people would consider that to be supported.

Comment: Thanks, both are great ideas.  Thanks everyone for the thoughts...some good stuff to keep in mind.  Frankly I'd rather keep it in house, and manage it ourselves.  But like mentioned above, the powers-that-be like that warm warm blanket.  Sigh....corporate BS....

Answer (score 0):

We have used CrushFTP for over a year and it works very well, has a low cost and support has been fantatsic (especially given the cost).

It has a small footprint and many great features.  It can be branded with your logo easily and it can be configured to ban the IP when a typical brute force attack happens.

We have not moved to version 5.x as yet.

[CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Serv-U](http://www.rhinosoft.com) which is pretty decent.  Support has worked well for us.  However you'll need their FTP Voyager for a web front end client piece.